# how write soql query to get product pricebook from product

Tags: soql

I am having a custom object and having product as lookup. I need to query product price and display in a field of that custom object when record is saved.

how write soql query to get product pricebook from product

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are some specific problems that you run into? Are there multiple price books? If so, how do you know which price book to use?

Comment: Product is linked to the Pricebook via the PricebookEntry (unless you have customised this, in which case please provide the details), so I'm note sure how you can do this. The entity diagram is: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm